# Swift - IOS - Limited time features

Tags: ios, swift, date, in-app-purchase, nsuserdefaults

I want to make a limited time promotion of my app, if you download in that day there should be no advertising forever, how do I implement it?

I can put the in app purchase free but i want something more automatic

I already implemented in-app purchase but I don't know if I can automatize it with a code like

```
 if (date==27/07/2016){
      purchase()
        if (purchase ok)
            popup("congratulations")}
```

Apple allows code like this for in-app purchases?Which class I have to use to check day/month/year?

In alternative to in-app purchases I was thinking about NSUserDefaults but if the user deletes and redownloads the app he loses the feature,and i don't know what will happen with future updates
What can I use in alternative to in-app purchase to remove ads in a permanent way?

Comment: how secure do you need it to be? do you have a server? or user accounts? do you have any ideas? don't ask multiple questions at the same time.

Comment: you just asked four questions at the same time yourself @Wain :-)

Comment: At the very first run you can check the date, and if its promo date perform whatever you do after in-app so the local app will act as user purchased the in-app. But the problem is if user deletes the app and re-install, user cannot restore this settings, he will loose these data and have to purchase in-app again since he never purchased it before. you need some server side support to save some data if you don't want to use in-apps.

Comment: I don't have servers or user account

Answer (score 0):

Have two IAPs, both for the same thing. One is free, one not. Only have the button get the free one on the promo date.

Comment: My solution for now is one in-app purchase, set it to free during the promotion